# SASS Compass grid not working

Tags: css, grid, sass, compass-sass

I can't seem to get the core grid from compass to show up in my file. I'm correctly importing the reset from compass

"@import "compass/reset";

but when I add in

"@import "compass/layout/grid-background";

I get nothing. Do I need to add it to my containing div somehow?

Comment: Those double-quotes before your @ aren't really in your file right?!
And your compass watch process is also watching your changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grid-background doesn't contain any styles directly, it's just a set of variables, functions and mixins that you can apply to styles yourself to set up the grid.

here's a nice example of how to use it: [grid example](https://github.com/niclupien/compass-examples/wiki/Compass-Grid-Backgrounds)

Note that the styles for container, header, footer, etc are using mixins from grid-background, that's what you want to do.

reference docs here: [grid layout docs](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/layout/grid_background/#const-grid-background-column-width%5D)

and if you find it helpful to look at the source, you can find it atyour equivalent of:

~/.rvm/gems/ruby-xxx/gems/compass-xxx/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/layout/_grid-background.scss

Comment: Thank you. I actually ended up just using the blueprint grid, which was easy enough and quite intuitive (plus I didn't feel guilty about adding a ton of classes to the markup because SASS can calculate).

Comment: lately the trend is moving away from old-style grids, because of the design goal of having the css classes be purely semantic. The idea is to avoid baking in style assumptions into the selectors themselves. e.g. bad: .red-column4 { ... } good: .alert-module { ... }. This certainly helps with future maintenance as styles change. This is why the compass stuff is based around mixins.